# VirtualBox cannot detect a removable drive

Tags: virtualbox

How do I solve the problem that VirtualBox cannot detect a removable drive? I've already reset VirtualBox, but it doesn't really detect the flash drive. When I click on devices and select USB devices, it says that there is no device that is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the closed source version of virtualbox to use USB. In the latest version you also need to setup filters in the setting is the VM.